# Fetch inner html and inner text within a div tag using asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

i am using Html Agility Pack to fetch my require inner html and inner text code. here is the html page code.

```
<div id="product-info-shipping" class="product-info-shipping-pnl util-clearfix notranslate" data-widget-cid="widget-14">
```

```
<b>US $6.98</b>
<span class="shipping-to">to</span></span>
```

```
<span id="shipping-country">United States</span> 
<span class="shipping-via">via</span> 
<span id="shipping-company">DHL</span></a>
```

from code behind i used this:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(txt.Text);
HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='product-info-shipping']");
  string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
```

but it only takes text within that div. and i want to take all the html span tag, br tag etc code including text within that div.
Please tell me how to do this 
thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't rateNode.ToString(); work?

Comment: rateNode.ToString(); shows this   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
string rate = rateNode.InnerHtml
```

rather than

```
string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
```

Comment: It only take the html code but not text data within those tags

Comment: @saif `InnerHtml` should work. Try also `rateNode.OuterHtml` for testing purposes, it should give you the outer div tag and everything inside of it.

Comment: OuterHtml works but it only shows html part  but not text. i want to fetch both html and text